# Does Driverless AI from H2O.ai support mutivariate time series analysis?

Tags: driverless-ai

Does Driverless AI support mutivariate time series analysis?

I'm trying to do a Time Series Analysis Anomaly forecasting where I need to forecast the spikes in Incident Management ticket Count based upon the Geography (location) and the Type of ticket.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. When modeling with multivariate time series time series of interest is a target while the other time series will be used to make predictions. Data format looks exactly like in [this example](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/09/multivariate-time-series-guide-forecasting-modeling-python-codes/) (not specific to Driverless AI) or see H2O.ai docs for [concrete time series example](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/1-8-lts/docs/userguide/examples/walmart_timeseries_experiment/training_timeseries_model.html#Step-1:-Import-Data) where target time series is `Weekly_Sales` and other time series variables are `Temperature` and `Fuel_Price`.

There is a couple of settings relevant to multivariate time series setup:

- [Unavailable at Prediction Time](http://prerelease.h2o.ai/docs/userguide/experiment-settings.html#time-column): specify the other time series columns (besides target column) that will only have lag-related features created with it.
- [Probability to Create Non-Target Lag Features](http://prerelease.h2o.ai/docs/userguide/expert-settings.html#probability-to-create-non-target-lag-features): specify a probability value for creating non-target lag features (any value between 0 and 1). With multivariate time series this value may go as high as 0.9 or even 1 if no target lag should be used for predictions.

UPDATE

In the spirit of the question [Multivariate vs Multiple time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/365335/8464) adding more information on modeling time series with Driverless AI. It also supports *multiple time series* (vs. *multivariate time series* above) using [time groups columns (TGC)](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/1-8-lts/docs/userguide/time-series.html?highlight=time%20columns%20group#groups). In fact, any time series dataset is automatically parsed to identify such groups (alternatively, TGC are specified explicitly by user). Treating TGC as categorical Driverless AI constructs multiple time series - one for each unique combination of values in TGC.

The following settings let user refine how time series model utilizes TGC:

- [Consider TGC as Standalone Features](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/1-8-lts/docs/userguide/expert-settings.html#consider-time-groups-columns-as-standalone-features)
- [Which TGC Feature Types to Consider as Standalone Features](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/1-8-lts/docs/userguide/expert-settings.html#which-tgc-feature-types-to-consider-as-standalone-features)
- [Always Group by All Time Groups Columns for Creating Lag Features](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/1-8-lts/docs/userguide/expert-settings.html#always-group-by-all-time-groups-columns-for-creating-lag-features)

TGC feature operates in combination with multivariate time series, so for each group Driverless AI maintains multivariate times series functionality as described above.